# Parse response returned by googlemaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to access the start_address from the response object returned from GoogleMaps.

**Tried:**

```
response['start_address']
response['routes']['start_address']
response['routes']['legs']['start_address']
```

**Google Maps:**

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionsDisplay.setMap($gmap);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById(directionHtml));
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            alert(response['routes']['legs']['start_address']);
    }
});
```

**response.toSource()**

```
({routes:[
    {bounds:{ba:{b:53.51456, d:53.529900000000005}, V:{d:-1.1919300000000002, b:-1.1283400000000001}},
    copyrights:"Map data \xA92011 Tele Atlas", 
    legs:[
        {distance:{text:"5.9 km", value:5910}, 
        duration:{text:"11 mins", value:688}, 
        end_address:"18 Spring Lane, Sprotbrough, Doncaster DN5 7, UK", 
        end_location:{Pa:53.51555, Qa:-1.1919299999999566}, 
        start_address:"42 High St, Doncaster DN1 1, UK", start_location:{Pa:53.52307, Qa:-1.1337300000000141}, steps:[
ETC...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you provided I can only come up with this structure of the response (not complete of course):

```
// for testing purposes I assume to have the actual response 
// assigned to a response var
var response = {
routes:[{
        bounds:{ba:{b:53.51456, d:53.529900000000005}, V:{d:-1.1919300000000002, b:-1.1283400000000001}},
        copyrights:"Map data \xA92011 Tele Atlas", 
        legs:[{
                distance:{text:"5.9 km", value:5910}, 
                duration:{text:"11 mins", value:688}, 
                end_address:"18 Spring Lane, Sprotbrough, Doncaster DN5 7, UK", 
                end_location:{Pa:53.51555, Qa:-1.1919299999999566}, 
                start_address:"42 High St, Doncaster DN1 1, UK", start_location:{Pa:53.52307, Qa:-1.1337300000000141}
            }]
    }]
};
```

And if you do `response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address` it returns `42 High St, Doncaster DN1 1, UK`. The `routes` property is an array so there may be cases where you need to iterate to get different values from indexes, if that's the case just iterate over it and replace `0` with the iterator variable.